# How to map Same foreign key twice

Tags: mysql, hibernate

How to map Same foreign key twice? I am getting

> org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists:

Example

```
Table-->Location 
LocationId Location Name
1           Location  A
2           LocationB

Table Person-->
personId PerosonName Location CurrenLocation
1        XYZ          1          1
```

I did my hibernate mapping like

```
class Location{
   private int locationId;
   private String locationName;
   //Getter Setter
}
class Person {
   private int personId;
   private String personName;
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "LOCATION", nullable = false)
   private Location location;
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "CURRENT_LOCATION", nullable = false)
   private Location currentLocation;
   /Getter & setter
}
```

Can you please help me with the same?

Comment: Could you please post a richer stack trace of the exception?

Comment: All are trying to access same object

Comment: You noticed the missing `/` in the `/Getter & setter` command? But I guess that is not the problem.